# vb.net SQL SERVER "Incorrect Syntax near'='."

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview, syntax-error

Im having problem in displaying records in datagridview and i dont know how to fix it. the messagebox is display "Incorrect Syntax near'='. here's my code.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click


    Dim search As String = String.Empty
    search &= "select * from record"
    search &= "where identification=@identification;"

    Using conn As New SqlConnection("server=KENJOY_FMCD;database=humanresource;user=ayala747;password=4525422;")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
            With cmd
                .Connection = conn
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = search
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@identification", vsearch.Text)
            End With
            Try
                conn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim ds As New DataSet
                da.Fill(ds)

                If ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables.Count
                Else
                    MsgBox("Identification Number Not Found!")
                End If
                conn.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Add space before 'where'

Comment: Use the debugger to look at the query string....you need a space before `WHERE`.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Thank you I didnt notice that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL statement doesn't leave a space between the table name and the WHERE keyword, so it looks like:

```
select * from recordwhere identification=@identification;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a white space before your `where`:

```
search &= "select * from record "
' Here ------------------------^
search &= "where identification=@identification;"
```